# SQLAlchemy using filter to an encrypted column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

One of my table column in my MYSQL database is of type blob since it is encrypted. See the model below:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(EncryptedType(sa.String, secret_key, AesEngine, 'pkcs5'))
    lname = db.Column(EncryptedType(sa.String, secret_key, AesEngine, 'pkcs5'))
    fullname = db.Column(EncryptedType(sa.String, secret_key, AesEngine, 'pkcs5'))
```

I want to get the records in that table where the `fullname` column matches an expression. In other words, I want to do the ff:

```py
name_to_look = 'Vholran'
search = '%{}%'.format(name_to_look)
users = db.session.query(*User.__table__.columns).\
           filter(User.fullname.like(search)).all()
```

The above code doesn't work. However, the code below works just fine:

```py
users = db.session.query(*User.__table__.columns).\
           filter(User.fullname == 'Vholran').all()
```

How do I do this? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/issues/454)

Comment: is there a fix to this? I cant seem to find anything